# SELECTING SPECIFIC DATA IN ORACLE

Tags: oracle11g

I want to select data from oracle where in a certain column I get only where the number of characters in 10. 
PS: Not first ten characters of a field, but fields with only ten characters in them.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(COLUMN_X) = 10
```

There are several functions you can use, based on the value you want to compare to:

- `Char_LENGTH()` returns the length of a string in characters.
- `LENGTH()` returns the length of a string in bytes.
- `BIT_LENGTH()` returns the length in bits.